# Longest path in directed graph between two specified nodes

Tags: graphs

There is plenty of algorithms available online, but they do things exactly opposite of what i need:

1. Find longest path in a graph between any nodes.
2. Do not remember the path, just weight.

I need an algorithm that can return both weight and path itself. I have tried two things so far:

1. Dijkstra's algorithm with negative weights - works fine in most cases, sometimes returns shorter path (especially when source and tap are connected directly).
2. DFS search from source, applies weights. Seems to work better overall, but results are rarely optimal.

Is there an algorithm that is designed to solve that one specific problem?

Comment: This is NP-hard, so all known algorithms take exponential time in the worst case. See "Hamiltonian Path" (a very similar and more famous NP-hard problem).

Comment: It's not equal to Hamiltonian path. Hamiltonian path has to contain all nodes, while here it's not required. I'm doing more tests on "reversed Dijkstra", and it's definitely not the solution for this problem.

Comment: The question "Does a Hamiltonian Path exist in this graph?" is exactly equivalent to "Does the longest path in this graph contain all $n$ vertices?". So if you can find the longest path in a graph, you know whether or not there is a Hamiltonian Path.